# pop up for terms and conditions wihtout postback of parent page

Tags: jquery, popup, postback, popupwindow, modalpopup

I have a signup page with cloned jquery controls 
I need to open terms and condition page and on accepting terms and condition I will enable the signup button on parent page
I cannot post back parent page until final signup submission so I have to use a popup for terms and conditions i guess.
is that possible that I can send parameter to parent page without postback parent

Answer (score 0):

Could you put it in a hidden form element?

Comment: hidden form element on parent page?

Comment: If I understand what you are asking, yes I have other elements also on the page which are not dynamically created.I can add hidden element.but I dunno how to use popup technique to send back some value